# SKTransition crossFadeWithDuration not working as expected in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit, nsnotificationcenter

I am trying to transition between two SKScenes using NSNotificationCenter, but for some reason crossFadeWithDuration does not work properly when using NSNotificationCenter from my SKScene.

By "not properly" I mean the current SKScene will begin to fade to black before the new SKScene begins to blend in, kind of like the regular fadeWithDuration method.

Here's my code:

In my ViewController, I post this in my viewDidLoad:

```
    let crossFade = SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(5.0)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "bubblePop:", name:"openBubblePop", object: nil)
```

I call this in my SKScene:

```
func loadGame(sender: String) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("openBubblePop", object: self)
}
```

And this is the block it runs in my ViewController:

```
func bubblePop(_:NSNotificationCenter) {
    skView.presentScene(BubblePop(size: skView.bounds.size), transition: crossFade)
}
```

I have tried calling the same presentScene line through a UIButton and the transition works as expected. Does anyone have any ideas to why this is working this way?

**Update**
I have filed a bug report with Apple about this issue. CrossFadeWithDuration is only working properly if running on iOS 8, and runs incorrectly in iOS 7 and 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use NSNotificationCenter at all? From you SKScene call:

```
self.view?.presentScene(BubblePop(size: (self.view?.bounds.size)!), transition: SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(5.0))
```

Comment: I have to use it because in most situations I have my ViewController do other things in the same method.

Comment: You don't include those things in the code you provide. Try doing the transition in your SKScene and post the notification to do the other things in your view controller